# Getting currently playing song with Spotipy gives error: "'Spotify' object has no attribute 'currently_playing'"

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm programming a script that returns your currently playing song from Spotify.

I read the documentation from Spotify API and everything is working well but I have some problems trying to implement some modules.

For example here https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ said that there's a module called `currently_playing()` but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spotify_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    current_song = sp.currently_playing()
AttributeError: 'Spotify' object has no attribute 'currently_playing'
```

By far, this is my code, it works well when I change the scope and the module to obtain the playlists of a user. So the token is not the problem.

```
import sys
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print('Usage %s Username ' % (sys.argv[0],))
    sys.exit()

scope = 'user-read-currently-playing'

token = spotipy.util.prompt_for_user_token(
    username, scope, redirect_uri='http://127.0.0.1/callback')

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    current_song = sp.currently_playing()

else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)


print(current_song)
```

Comment: Have you tried `current_user_playing_track()`?

Comment: Yes, sadly I receive the same error: AttributeError: 'Spotify' object has no attribute 'current_user_playing_track'. I uninstalled and installed spotipy again and I checked the current version, which is 2.4.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/spotipy/) claims that the version of Spotipy is the latest there, 2.4.4, in fact, it is not. I noticed that after installing Spotipy with pip, its source code is different from the head of the master branch on the [GitHub](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy). And the PyPi version doesn't have the `currently_playing` method.

What worked for me is to uninstall Spotipy by running `pip uninstall spotipy` and to install it again directly from GitHub:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/plamere/spotipy.git@master
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! It worked perfectly after uninstall and install directly from github as you said!